How to mount the local filesystem with stlite
I'm trying to create an executable from a streamlit app using stlite. I need the app to read and write files on the local filesystem, so I followed these explanations. Even with the example provided here, I always get an error like this:
Error during boot up

Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, node, and electron are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'

A popup also shows the trace (sorry for the screenshot, the popup doesn't let me select the text):

I thought that this had to do with the way the path is specified in package.json:
       "nodefsMountpoints": {
          "/mnt": "."
        }

so I tried a few variants, with file:///c:/... but it always ended with the same error.
Any suggestion welcome, thanks!

maybe you should use 2 / instead 3 / afert file: - file://c:/.... OR maybe try without c: like file:///folder/... - but  I don't use Windows to check it.

I found only this Generate "file://" URIs in Windows Explorer - Super User

in this question I see ideas like //computer_name/c$/folder but I don't know if it works with file// url - How to specify a local file within html using the file: scheme? - Stack Overflow

@furas thank you for your suggestions, but no luck. It seems that it's not related to how the mounted dir is specified, because the error always mentions "received protocol c:" even if I don't have 'c:' in the path. Also normally a relative path like "." should work, but it doesn't.

maybe you should ask authors of this module how to do it. And if they don't know how to do it then they may fix it.

This error was solved in stlite 0.58.1, thanks to the author!
